# Access predictions from repeated k-fold cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I want to do a prediction using k-fold cross validation and, in the end, store all the predictions in a file.

I am able to do a prediction and get the accuracy, this is how I did it:

```
cv1 = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)

model = LogisticRegression()

scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv1, n_jobs=-1)
print('Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

But I do not find any way or function that allows me to access the actual predictions.
In the end, I want to get an output containing each data point's id and the predicted label.

I tried to find a way to access the predictions using

```
cross_val_predict(model, X, y, cv=cv1, method='predict')
```

but this function does not work when using `RepeatedKFold` cross validation.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Do you get an error or what? Please do not answer here, edit & update your post accordingly.

Comment: With `RepeatedKFold(n_repeats=3, ...)`, you'll get three predicted values per row.  Do you care whether the predictions are assigned to their repetition?  Do you need to know the folds used for each repetition?